Do the British see the American their “descendants”
I mean this as in cultural and not literal genetics.

This doesn't appear to be a question about history. It's more about the opinions of those currently living. I think that if you did a genetic sample of the current American population, you'd discover that only a minority of them are actually descended from the British colonists.

Please revise to be in scope for history and to permit an authoritative answer.

A good beginner's rule of thumb is that if your question isn't posed in the past tense, its probably off-topic here.
